# Form<Void> in Wicket (or usage of the Void type in general)

Tags: java, generics, wicket

Came across code recently in Wicket like so:

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form")
```

Can anyone explain the usage of the Void type here?  First time I've seen that type being used actually. Is it used t all outside of Wicket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's used outside of Wicket. For example, when a method takes a `Callable<V>` as argument, and my Callable doesn't return anything, I use a `Callable<Void>`. `Void` is thus used to indicate that some parameterized method doesn't return anything.

In this particular case, according to the documentation, it's used to indicate that the Form doesn't have any model object. The only valid value of the Void type is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

`Void` is sometimes used as the type parameter in cases when you want to express that you "don't want to return anything" or "don't want to pass anything" in the type. i.e. a [unit type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) that holds no information. Because a type parameter has to be a reference type, and `null` is a value of all reference types, the desired type would not have any other values, i.e. is a type with no instances. The "null type" itself would work, but it doesn't have name. So we pick an arbitrary class that doesn't have any instances, and `Void` is a convenient choice. Technically any other non-instantiatable class, like the utility classes `Math` or `Collections`, would work just as well; but `Void` seems more appropriate because of its relation to `void`, the type that is used to express a unit type within primitive types.